# Android: How to implement numeric keypad?

Tags: android

I have an edit text with a background image. When i click on the edit text i should enter numericals.
So, I should dispaly a numeric keypad. I did this by android: inputtype = "Phone" method. But iam not getting numeric keypad. Please help me>?

Comment: what you want to do exactly? you mean you want only numeric keypad when user click on edittext  or what else?

Comment: S. I want numeric keypad to appear when user click on edit text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this You need to set the EditText's Input type property to number .

android:inputType="number"

Comment: please click on the edittext the keyboard open in the number mode

Comment: or You mean to say that when Your activity is call the softkeyboard automatically open ??

Comment: please paste your xml and class file

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
  editview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Best 
V.k

Comment: Add this in your java file with the editview.It is working for me.Try this hope this will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

you have  two solutions for that

the 1st one is to do it in the layout like that android:inputType=""... see below lastline:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/getLat" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:cursorVisible="true" 
        android:editable="true" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
      />
```

Comment: can you show your code, perhaps i can test it over here to see if your emul not working..
what do you have instead?